# Center text within a span element

Tags: tailwind-css

I can't get the text of a span element to be centered. I have the following code to try

```
   <div className="relative border-2">
    <div className="h-full">
      <Image
        alt="image_1"
        fill
        style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
        src="..."
      ></Image>
    </div>
    <span className="absolute top-1 right-1 text-center bg-wabu-keppel text-black font-bold h-10 w-10 rounded-full">
      4
    </span>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <span className="absolute top-1 right-1 text-center bg-wabu-keppel text-black font-bold h-10 w-10 rounded-full grid place-items-center">
  4
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "center" with respect to the vertical and horizontal axes, you could apply:

- ```css
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  ```

  via `flex items-center justify-center` classes
- ```css
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  ```

  via `grid place-items-center` classes

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="relative border-2 w-80">
  <div class="h-full">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/100" width=320 height=100 />
  </div>
  <span class="absolute top-1 right-1 text-center bg-red-200 text-black font-bold h-10 w-10 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center">
      4
    </span>
</div>

<div class="relative border-2 w-80">
  <div class="h-full">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/320/100?" width=320 height=100 />
  </div>
  <span class="absolute top-1 right-1 text-center bg-red-200 text-black font-bold h-10 w-10 rounded-full grid place-items-center">
      4
   </span>
</div>
```